How to Handle Hangfire with Dynamic Connection Strings Based on URL in ASP.NET Core 7 MVC Multi-Tenant Application?
I'm working on a multi-tenant ASP.NET Core 7 MVC application where each tenant has its own database. The connection string changes based on the URL, with each URL corresponding to a different tenant and its specific database connection string. I need to integrate Hangfire to handle background jobs, but I'm facing challenges with configuring Hangfire to use dynamic connection strings based on the tenant. Additionally, I need to handle the Hangfire Dashboard to show data specific to the current tenant.
Here is the setup I currently have:
ASP.NET Core 7 MVC
Multi-tenancy implementation
Different connection strings for different tenants, determined by the URL
Hangfire for background job processing
My Problem:
I need to configure Hangfire to use the correct connection string for each tenant dynamically. However, I'm not sure how to properly set up Hangfire in a multi-tenant environment where the connection string changes based on the URL. I also need to configure the Hangfire Dashboard to display data for the current tenant only.
What I've Tried:
Custom Middleware: I implemented custom middleware to intercept the request and set the connection string.
Dynamic DbContext: Attempted to configure the DbContext dynamically based on the connection string stored in the HttpContext.
Example Code:
Tenant Middleware:
public class TenantResolutionMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

    public TenantResolutionMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        _next = next;
    }

    public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context, ITenantService tenantService)
    {
        try
        {
            await tenantService.IdentifyTenant(context);
            var tenant = await tenantService.GetCurrentTenantAsync(context);
            if (tenant != null)
            {
                context.Items["ConnectionString"] = tenant.ConnectionString;
                context.Items["TenantConnectionString"] = tenant.ConnectionString;
                context.Items["TenantId"] = tenant.Id;
            }
            else
            {
                var defaultConnectionString = context.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<IConfiguration>().GetConnectionString("Web");
                context.Items["ConnectionString"] = defaultConnectionString;
                context.Items["TenantConnectionString"] = defaultConnectionString;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            context.Response.StatusCode = 500; // Internal Server Error
            await context.Response.WriteAsync("An error occurred while identifying the tenant.");
            return;
        }
        await _next(context);
    }
}


Initialize Tenant Databases:
public static void InitializeTenantDatabases(this WebApplication app)
{
    using var scope = app.Services.CreateScope();
    var tenantService = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<ITenantService>();

    var tenants = tenantService.GetAllTenants();

    foreach (var tenant in tenants)
    {
        using var tenantScope = app.Services.CreateScope();
        var dbContext = tenantScope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<ApplicationDbContext>();

        dbContext.Database.SetConnectionString(tenant.ConnectionString);
        dbContext.Database.Migrate();

        var dataInitializers = tenantScope.ServiceProvider.GetServices<IDataInitializer>();
        foreach (var dataInitializer in dataInitializers)
            dataInitializer.InitializeData();
    }
}


ITenantService Interface:
public interface ITenantService
{
    Task IdentifyTenant(HttpContext context);
    Task<Entities.Tenant.Tenant> GetCurrentTenantAsync(HttpContext context);
    string GetCurrentTenantConnectionString();
    Guid GetCurrentTenantId();
    string GetCurrentTenantIdString();
    Entities.Tenant.Tenant GetCurrentTenant();
    Task<Entities.Tenant.Tenant> GetCurrentTenantAsyncCashing(HttpContext context);
    string GetConnectionStringByTenantId(Guid tenantId);
    string GetDatabaseProvider();
    IEnumerable<Entities.Tenant.Tenant> GetAllTenants();
}


What I'm Looking For:
How to configure Hangfire to dynamically use the correct connection string for each tenant based on the URL.
How to handle the Hangfire Dashboard to show data specific to the current tenant.
Examples or resources on how to properly implement Hangfire in a multi-tenant ASP.NET Core 7 MVC application.
Any potential pitfalls or best practices I should be aware of when integrating Hangfire with multi-tenancy.
I tried implementing custom middleware to set the connection string based on the URL and integrating it with Hangfire. I expected Hangfire to use the correct connection string for each tenant dynamically and execute background jobs for each tenant using their respective databases.
Expected Result:
Hangfire would dynamically pick up the connection string from the middleware and execute jobs for the correct tenant database.
The Hangfire Dashboard would display data specific to the current tenant.
Actual Result:
Hangfire did not use the dynamic connection string, and background jobs failed to connect to the correct tenant database.
The Hangfire Dashboard did not show tenant-specific data.

There are a couple different approaches you can use. The first potential issue would be trying to use a static initialization for the DbContexts. I would recommend having a separate bounded DbContext for Authentication/Authorization which all sessions rely on, which includes retrieving the relevant tenant connection string. The Tenant-specific application DbContext should be scoped to the web request or even shorter which means that it should be initialized with the tenant applicable for the current session.
From there you can consider one of the following three approaches:

Introduce something like a SessionService helper to wrap the current authenticated session state to inject into the DbContext. Here the DbContext initialization would get the connection string from the ISessionService injected by the IoC container which would return the connection string specific to the current session user.

Configure the IoC container to build the DbContext on demand. This will depend on the IoC Container you are using, personally I use Autofac for its configurability. So instead of a single configurable connection string:
builder.RegisterType<AppDbContext>()
    .WithParameter(new NamedParameter("connectionString", connectionString))
    .AsSelf();



Register to resolve on demand:
    builder.Register<AppDbContext>(context =>
    {   // However you want to fetch the connection string, from the container or a static Singleton, etc.
        ISessionService sessionService = context.Resolve<ISessionService>();
        var connectionString = sessionService.ConnectionString;
        // TODO: Validate and handle if the session times out or doesn't return a connection string.
        return new AppDbContext(connectionString);
    });


Instead of injecting a DbContext you can inject an IDbContextFactory which wraps the current session checking for a connection string and initializes a DbContext on demand with the desired connection string.


thanks , but not work

Keep in mind that if you are implementing a background service model then your payload for the service will need to include an identifier for the tenant to resolve the connection string when a worker picks up that tenant's request. I would lean towards using a DbContext Factory dependency for this reason. The worker handler parses the tenant from the payload it picks up, gets the connection string, then calls a using context = Factory.CreateContext(connectionString); .
